# How to marshall an unwrapped collection in JAXB?

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

This is my class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "foo")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Foo {
  @XmlElement
  public Collection getElements() {
    List elements = new ArrayList();
    elements.add(new Bar);
    elements.add(new Bar);
    return elements;
  }
}
```

Class `Bar` is also simple:

```
@XmlType(name = "bar")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public static final class Bar {
  @XmlElement
  public String getMessage() {
    return "hello, world!";
  }
}
```

This is what I'm getting after marshalling of `Foo`:

```
<foo>
  <elements xsi:type="foo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <message>hello, world!</message>
  </elements>
  <elements xsi:type="foo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <message>hello, world!</message>
  </elements>
</foo>
```

While I'm expecting to get:

```
<foo>
  <bar>
    <message>hello, world!</message>
  </bar>
  <bar>
    <message>hello, world!</message>
  </bar>
</foo>
```

What should I fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to annotate the `elements` property with `@XmlElement(name="bar")`:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "foo")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Foo {
  @XmlElement(name="bar")
  public Collection getElements() {
    List elements = new ArrayList();
    elements.add(new Bar);
    elements.add(new Bar);
    return elements;
  }
}
```

Comment: But I want to use their names from their `@XmlType` annotations. I don't want to duplicate this declaration in `Foo` class... Possible? Moreover, in a real life example I don't know what their names are.

Comment: @yegor256 - Instead of the value of the `@XmlType` annotation, you can leverage the value of the `@XmlRootElement` annotation.  If the values of the collection are involved in an inheritance hierarchy you can leverage the `@XmlElementRef` annotation:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html.  If they are not related you can use the `@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)` annotation: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/using-xmlanyelement-to-build-generic.html